# How to trigger completion using company mode and tide?

Tags: completion, company-mode

I use `tide` for editing TypeScript files with default setup from documentation using company mode. I was just watching a tutorial about Prisma (TypeScript ORM) that uses VS Code and shows an available option when typing object literals `{}`; with `tide+company mode` I have completion only when I type dot and access nested objects.

Is there a way to trigger company mode with available options inside objects like in VS Code?

This is the video I was watching look at time 1:05:

[image]

is something like this possible with `tide`?

Comment: What does the documentation for `tide` have to say on the subject?

Comment: @db48x I can't find it in the documentation, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: You might want to try an LSP-based solution.